# what is ten divided by eighty (i have ten dollars that i want to divide into eighty groups)

Tags: divisibility

Ok so if i draw out 10/80 in the oldschool format with a long division [symbol](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LongDivisionSymbol.html) what are the steps to solve?

Would it be correct to say 'how many times does ten go into eighty'? I tried to draw this out then circle them into groups but then I realized that all 80 groups would have less than one whole unit.

Comment: should be "how many eighties go into ten?"

Comment: How would you divide $\$1$ into $8$ groups?  You would need *half-penny* coins.

Comment: Some countries may have half-pennies. The US used to: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half_cent_(United_States_coin)

Comment: All I know is there were 80 trash bags that cost 10$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite. It would be correct to ask: "How many times does $80$ go into $10$." The entire division process would look like the following:
\begin{align*}
&\underline{\ \  0 .125}\\
80)&10.000\\
-&\underline{\ \ \  80}\\
& \ \ \ 200\\
-&\ \ \ \underline{160}\\
& \ \ \ \ \ 400\\
& -\underline{400}\\
& \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 0\\
\end{align*}

If this does not make sense, I can add an image with better details; let me know!

Comment: Then I think OP will want to know, how does one interpret the quotient, $0.125$?

Comment: Thank you! Gerry, I think I know how to interpret it. .125 is equal to 1/8. Seems like there might be multiple ways to solve but I don't know. I just forgot the steps.

Comment: Yes, Jordan, it's one-eighth – but how do you interpret this in the context of dividing ten dollars into $80$ groups?